# Add dynamic pathfield(rootPath) for cq5 component

Tags: aem

How can we add a dynamic pathfield(rootPath) for a cq5 component?

Are there any example references?

Comment: Could you write something more? What does it mean that rootPath should be dynamic? How it should be obtained?

Comment: Example: rootPath value
/content/myproject/locale/mycomponent/pages

Here i wants to add the "locale" information dynamically according to my page specific locale information(like, en/fr/ar/etc..)
So that rootPath value should appear as 
For a English page
/content/myproject/en/mycomponent/
For French
/content/myproject/fr/mycomponent/
For Arabic
/content/myproject/ar/mycomponent/
etc..

Answer (score 10):

I think you should use custom widget plugin. First, add property `plugins` to your `pathfield` in the `dialog.xml`:

```
<myPathComponent
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    fieldLabel="My path component"
    plugins="customRootPathPlugin"
    xtype="pathfield" />
```

Then create custom ExtJS plugin. In order to do that, create new JS file, and add it to [clientlib](http://experiencedelivers.adobe.com/cemblog/en/experiencedelivers/2012/12/clientlibs-explained-by-example.html) with `cq.wcm.edit` category. Plugin can look like that:

```
(function($) {
    var plugin = CQ.Ext.extend(CQ.Ext.emptyFn, {
        init: function(widget) {
            var locale = "en";

            // create some JS logic to get the locale here
            // current path can be obtained via
            // widget.findParentByType('dialog').responseScope.path
            widget.treeRoot.name = "content/myproject/" + locale + "/mycomponent";
        }
    });

    CQ.Ext.ComponentMgr.registerPlugin('customRootPathPlugin', plugin);
}($CQ));
```

Comment: Can you show full code of dialog.xml ?I have problems)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But I am trying to achieve this using xtype "paragraphreference" . when i am using paragraph reference i am not getting widget.treeRoot as 'undefined'.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Tomek's answer, I was able to get the current page and then display all the siblings and children with this:

```
(function($) {
var plugin = CQ.Ext.extend(CQ.Ext.emptyFn, {
    init : function(widget) {
        var url = CQ.HTTP.getPath();
        widget.treeRoot.name = url.substring(1, url.lastIndexOf('/') );
    }
});
CQ.Ext.ComponentMgr.registerPlugin('customRootPathPlugin', plugin);}($CQ));
```

The reason I did `url.substring(1`  instead of `url.substring(0` is because I would end up with double forward slash `//content/app/en/` in the dialog.