# "Uncaught Type Error — "has no method 'apply'" — when implementing a CQ5 dialog listener

Tags: extjs, aem

I am trying to update a field in the `dialog.xml` based on the value of another field in the dialog. It works when I add the code directly using the CRXDELite, but fails when I deploy via Maven from Eclipse.

My intuition says it's a formatting problem, since I usually use the plain text editor in Mac before pasting the JS into the CRXDELite.

The code and the error received are below. This is using CQ5.5.

**dialog.xml:**

```
<options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
    <contentvideo jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" 
                  text="valuetocheckfor"     
                  value="valuetocheckfor"/>
        <product  jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" 
                  text="duh" 
                  value="duh"/>
</options>
<listeners jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            selectionchanged="function(box,value){
                var ans = box.findParentByType('dialog').form.findField('./fieldtochange');
                disableAnsText(ans,value);
            }
            function disableAnsText(ans,value) {
                if(value == 'valuetocheckfor') {
                    console.log('anstype value - '+value);
                    ans.setDisabled(true);
                    ans.getEl().up('.x-form-item').setDisplayed(false);
                } else {
                    ans.getEl().up('.x-form-item').setDisplayed(true);
                    ans.setDisabled(false);
                }

            }"/>
```

**Exception in the browser:**

`Uncaught TypeError: Object function(box,value){...my function } has no method 'apply' widgets.js:1249`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`selectionchanged` property expects that you'll pass an anonymous function, so it can `apply` method on it. You have put some Javascript code containing two definitions, one after another:

```
function(box,value) {
   ... 
}

function disableAnsText(ans,value) {
   ...
}
```

This code fragment is not a function declaration, so CQ can't invoke `apply` and hence the exception. As a quick-fix you can move `disableAnsText` function inside the anonymous function:

```
function(box,value) {
   function disableAnsText(ans,value) {
      // disableAnsText function body
   }
   // anonymous function body
}
```

Please notice that this fragment of the dialog configuration is quite unreadable. It is a good idea to move the whole logic to the [client library](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/clientlibs.html). Widget listener configuration should only contain an invocation of the function declared in the clientlib.

Alternatively, you could consider rewriting this logic to the form of a [widget plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029410/add-dynamic-pathfieldrootpath-for-cq5-component) which is even cleaner solution.

Comment: Solution does not work.Thanks for the answer. I have used this solution with no results. Also this does not justify why I when I use my code directly in crxde lite, it works.

Comment: apologies. Your solution works. I tried it again and had some typos.