# How to configure a rootPath in CQ Dialog depending on current page

Tags: extjs, aem

I have the following `CQ dialog.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0" jcr:primaryType="cq:TabPanel"
    activeTab="{Long}0" title="mContactConnect_dialogtitle" headerAsText="true"
    xtype="tabpanel">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <tab1 jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" anchor="100%" title="myTitle"
            xtype="panel">
            <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                <subheadline jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" fieldLabel="subheadline_label"
                    name="./subheadline" maxLength="80" xtype="textfield"/>
                <text jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" fieldLabel="text_label" name="./text"
                    maxLength="150" xtype="textfield"/>
                <reference jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" fieldLabel="reference_label"
                    name="./reference" forceSelection="true" xtype="pathfield" rootPath ="/content" />
            </items>
        </tab1>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

Now I would like to reference to certain rootPath depnding on current page. 
For this, I extend the PathField as follow:

```
myExtendedRootPath = CQ.Ext.extend(CQ.Ext.emptyFn, {
    init : function(widget) {
        var currentPath;
        var siteAdmin = CQ.Ext.getCmp("cq-siteadmin");

        if (siteAdmin) {
            currentPath = siteAdmin.getSelectedPages().shift().id;
        } else {CQ.Ext.
            currentPath = CQ.utils.WCM.getPagePath();
        }

        if (currentPath =="page1") {
            widget.treeRoot.name = "content/page1";
        }
        else if (currentPath =="page2") {
            widget.treeRoot.name = "content/page2";
        }
    }
});

CQ.Ext.reg("myExtendedRootPath", myExtendedRootPath.init());
```

I follow the function call with firebug. For this I set breakpoint on the line `init : function(widget) {`. When I step forward, the steppointer jump to the last line `CQ.Ext.reg...`

Why the `init` Function not call?

Comment: Not sure how much this helps but you can add id as xml attribute to the path field and then try accessing it by using CQ.Ext.getCmp("id value added to the pathfield").setRootPath("This path will be the dynamic path"); add this to js file which is loaded from the jsp

Comment: Initially, you've used `dmyExtendedRootPath` and after that `myExtendedRootPath` — is that a typo?

Comment: http://labs.sixdimensions.com/blog/2014-04-07/cq-dialog-dynamically-generate-rootpath/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Register created object as a plugin. Replace the last line with:

   ```
   CQ.Ext.ComponentMgr.registerPlugin('myExtendedRootPath', myExtendedRootPath);
   ```
2. Add registered plugin to the `reference` dialog field:

   ```
   <reference
       jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
       fieldLabel="reference_label"
       name="./reference"
       forceSelection="true"
       xtype="pathfield"
       rootPath ="/content"
       plugins="myExtendedRootPath" />
   ```
3. Fix syntax error (unexpected `CQ.Ext.`):

   ```
   if (siteAdmin) {
       currentPath = siteAdmin.getSelectedPages().shift().id;
   } else {CQ.Ext. // <-- here
       currentPath = CQ.utils.WCM.getPagePath();
   }
   ```

Optionally, find a working example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029410/add-dynamic-pathfieldrootpath-for-cq5-component/19046632#19046632).

Answer (score 0):

This is for all those who maybe interested in setting the defaultValue of a pathfield component dynamically. This worked for me to set the value to the current page-path:

(Follow the plugin src code as mentioned above). Then, use this:

```
widget.setValue(cq.utils.WCM.getPagePath()).
```

What was interesting was that I had to actually manually define a 'defaultValue' field in the dialog.xml before the line above successfully worked! Strange.. so my dialog would look as the follows:

```
<reference
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    fieldLabel="reference_label"
    name="./reference"
    forceSelection="true"
    xtype="pathfield"
    defaultValue="/content/any/random/string"
    plugins="myExtendedRootPath" />
```