# cq5. using pathField xtype in dialog

Tags: dialog, components, aem

I want to use pathfield in dialog of my component.

According [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19046632/2674303)

I added

```
<myPathComponent
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        fieldLabel="My path component"
        plugins="customRootPathPlugin"
        xtype="pathfield" />
```

to my dialog.xml

I tryed differents varians:

### 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
    title="Example Component Dialog"
    xtype="dialog">
    <items
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        xtype="tabpanel">
        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <tab1                
             <myPathComponent
                  jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                  fieldLabel="My path component"
                  plugins="customRootPathPlugin"
                  xtype="pathfield" />

            />
        </items>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

### 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
    title="Example Component Dialog"
    xtype="dialog">
    <items
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        xtype="tabpanel">
        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">

             <myPathComponent
                  jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                  fieldLabel="My path component"
                  plugins="customRootPathPlugin"
                  xtype="pathfield" />


        </items>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

### 3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
    title="Example Component Dialog"
    xtype="dialog">
    <items
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        xtype="tabpanel">


             <myPathComponent
                  jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                  fieldLabel="My path component"
                  plugins="customRootPathPlugin"
                  xtype="pathfield" />



    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

### 4

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
    title="Example Component Dialog"
    xtype="dialog">



             <myPathComponent
                  jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                  fieldLabel="My path component"
                  plugins="customRootPathPlugin"
                  xtype="pathfield" />




</jcr:root>
```

### 5

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"



             <myPathComponent
                  jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                  fieldLabel="My path component"
                  plugins="customRootPathPlugin"
                  xtype="pathfield" />




</jcr:root>
```

only in some cases after double click by component I see component reaction. But there are arise empty  list :

[image]

What I need to read for resolve my problem ?

Comment: Have you defined your "customRootPathPlugin"? Does your developer console(F12) show any errors??

Comment: @rakhi4110 Where can I know about define or not define I customRootPathPlugin ?

Comment: @rakhi4110, which page I need to press f12 ?

Answer (score 0):

The linked answer presented how to implement an dynamic pathfield (eg. one that allows to set different root path depending on the current site). If you'd like to create a dialog with a single, normal pathfield widget, following code will do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
  jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
  title="Simple dialog"
  xtype="dialog">
  <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
    <tabPanel
      jcr:primaryType="cq:TabPanel"
      xtype="tabpanel">
      <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <tab1
          jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
          anchor="100%"
          title="General"
          xtype="panel">
          <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <myPathComponent
              jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
              fieldLabel="My path component"
              xtype="pathfield" />
          </items>
        </tab1>
      </items>
    </tabPanel>
  </items>
</jcr:root>
```

Comment: Is somewhere place where can I find any xtype-s and minimal attributes for using(maybe with examples)?

Comment: [Adobe documentation](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/widgets/xtypes.html) contains a list.

Comment: this link from your link. How should I understand **minimal set attributes for using this xtype** ? examples?