# show current page path in paragraph reference in AEM

Tags: aem

I am having dialog with xtype field as "paragraphreference". When i open the field it is showing the whole content repository. I want to show only current page path in the paragraph reference field. I dont want to overlay the js file. Is there any other solution or property which can give the current page path to show.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with custom widget plugin. First, add property plugins to your pathfield in the dialog.xml:

```
<myPathComponent
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    fieldLabel="My path component"
    plugins="customRootPathPlugin"
    xtype="pathfield" />
```

Then create custom ExtJS plugin. In order to do that, create new JS file, and add it to clientlib with cq.wcm.edit category. Plugin can look like that:

```
(function($) {
var plugin = CQ.Ext.extend(CQ.Ext.emptyFn, {
    init: function(widget) {
       var currentPath = CQ.WCM.getPagePath();
        widget.treeRoot.name = currentPath;
    }
});

CQ.Ext.ComponentMgr.registerPlugin('customRootPathPlugin', plugin);
```

}($CQ));

Also you can take ref from : [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029410/add-dynamic-pathfieldrootpath-for-cq5-component/19046632#19046632)

Comment: I know that. But I need to show the current page path in dialog tree. As of now, it is showing whole tree from content.

Comment: @Manan You can do it with custom widget plugin as above.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But I am trying to achieve this using xtype "paragraphreference" . when i am using paragraph reference i am getting widget.treeRoot as 'undefined'